# Fetching table data from webpage using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am very new to web scraping. I have the following url:

https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/symbolsearch

So, I use Selenium to enter the Symbol Textbox and press Find Symbols to get the details. This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/symbolsearch/")
element = driver.find_element_by_id("query")
element.send_keys("WMT:US")
driver.find_element_by_name("commit").click()
```

It returns the table. How can I retrieve that? I am pretty clueless.

Second question,
Can I do this without Selenium as it is slowing down things? Is there a way to find an API which returns a JSON?

Comment: https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/symbolsearch/")
element = driver.find_element_by_id("query")
element.send_keys("WMT:US")
driver.find_element_by_name("commit").click()
time.sleep(5)
url = driver.current_url
time.sleep(5)

parsed = requests.get(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(parsed.content,'html.parser')
a = soup.findAll("table", { "class" : "dual_border_data_table" })

print(a)
```

here is the total code by which you can get the table you are looking for. now do what you need to do after getting the table. hope it helps